# How can you construct the bijection between real numbers and functions over naturals?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, computability

I was reading "Classical Recursion Theory" by Odifreddi and it starts with this phrase:

> Recall that Classical Recursion Theory is the study of real numbers or, equivalently, functions over the natural numbers.

I come from Computer Science so this was puzzling to me at first. I understand he's referring to the fact that there is a bijection between $\mathbb{N}$ $\rightarrow$ $\mathbb{N}$ and $\mathbb{R}$. I know that |$\mathbb{N}$ $\rightarrow$ $\mathbb{N}$| is greater than |$\mathbb{N}$| (Cantor's diagonal), but how can you find the real $x$ corresponding to a certain function?

I know that given a real $x$ we can construct a function like this: $f(n) =$ the $n$-th digit of $x$. But what is the other way around? We can't use digits in this case, I think, because we have numbers with more than one digit; I don't think changing the digit system would help (I think every digit system has a finite alphabet?) and that way we would link more functions to the same real number.

I know that you can't compute reals in a strict sense (you would need $\infty$ digits) but I was wondering if there was at least some sketch-procedure of how to represent a function with a real number, to have at least logically a glimpse of what is the number $x$ corresponding to a generic function $f$: $\mathbb{N}$ $\rightarrow$ $\mathbb{N}$.

Comment: post scriptum: I come from CS and I'm not a native english speaker. I've tried to search the site and google for an answer but I can't find anything, perhaps due to my low knowledge of the terminology. If it's a duplicate, let me know (I've found similar questions but they all dealt with smaller subsets of functions).

Comment: I think you can map a function $f: \mathbb{N} \rightarrow \{1, .., n\}$ to the decimal expansion of a real number in base $n$. You can then argue, that the set of functions $\mathbb{N} \rightarrow \{1, .., n\}$ is the same size as $\mathbb{N} \rightarrow \mathbb{N}$.

Comment: Mind that, as a general principle, you may know that two sets have the same cardinality without being able to define an explicit bijection.

Comment: @quarague do you mean $n$ as the greatest value of $f$? In that case, wouldn't we let out functions without a maximum? Such as $f(n)=n$.

Comment: @NetHacker I think you are right, this is not a bijection. It's still surjective, so maybe one can modify it a bit.

Comment: @AndreaMori that's reasonable. I just assumed it was possible because of that sentence I quoted, which made me think that you can easily pass from one set to the other one (as you can do it, for instance, from the set of naturals to the set of turing machines).

Answer (score 1):

Here's an idea I didn't check in detail, but maybe it helps:

Let $x_0\ge 0$ be any real number and recursively define for $n\in\mathbb N=\{0,1,\dots\}$:
\begin{align*}
a_n &= \lfloor x_n \rfloor, \\
x_{n+1} &= g(x_n-a_n),
\end{align*}
for $g$ the bijection $[0,1)\to\mathbb R_{\ge 0}$ given by $g(x) = \frac{x}{1-x}$ with inverse given by $g^{-1}(y) = \frac{y}{1+y}$.

I claim that the map $\mathbb R_{\ge 0} \to \mathbb N^{\mathbb N}$ given by $x_0 \mapsto (a_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ is a bijection. Compose this with your favorite bijection between $\mathbb R_{\ge 0}$ and $\mathbb R$ to obtain what you asked for.